# EXC_BAD_ACCESS at random location iOS 9

Tags: objective-c, crash, ios9, exc-bad-access, xcode7

I am facing an issue with iOS 9. My app crashes randomly with EXC_BAD_ACCESS at random location. I tried using the debugger and putting breakpoints to check for any errors.Also tried with exception breakpoints but to no help. My app runs fine on iOS 8.4 and below without any error.

I tried enabling Zombie Objects.On enabling them the App does not crashes till it is connected with the computer for debugging. As soon as the cable is disconnected the app starts crashing.

Also while debugging with Zombie Object with or without breakpoints I don't get any crashes or exception or any log on the console.

If anymore information is required please revert back .

Answer (score 0):

There is a bunch of questions like this one and no general answer since the problem is that it can be caused by numerous reasons. I believe that in my case it was a bug because it has happened on random places. Luckily for me to clean a project has helped me.

So hit Shift+CMD+K and believe.

Comment: Viktor actually i was able to resolve the crash and it was basically due to non-arc code which did not manage and release some objects, observers and delegates. I used zombies and found which classes where the reason for the crash and performed release/remove/set to nil for the objects, observers and delegates respectively and then the app was running fine. Basically it was a memory management issue as iOS 9 is pretty conservative about memory. Helped in other projects also. Use Zombies and save life :P